# Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition, Ex. 15.2.25

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$

> Suppose $f(x) = x^{3}+ ax^{2}+bx+c$ is an irreducible cubic in $\Q[x]$
> of discriminant $D$. Let $I = (x+y+z+a, xy+xz+yz-b, xyz+c) $ in
> $\Q[x,y,z]$.
>
> (a) Prove that $I$ is a prime ideal if and only if $D$ is not a square
> in $\Q$, in which case $I$ is a maximal ideal and $\Q[x,y,z]/I$ is a
> splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\Q$.
>
> (b) If $D= r^{2}$, prove that
> the primary decomposition of $I$ is $I= Q_+\cap Q_-$ where
> $Q_\pm=(I,(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\pm r)$. Prove $Q_+$ and $Q_-$ are maximal
> ideals, and $\Q[x,y,z]$ modulo $Q_+$ or $Q_-$ is a splitting field for
> $f(x)$ over $\Q$.

I am working on above problem in Dummit and Foote's text, section 15.2, exercise 25.

Of course, if $f(x)$ is irreducible and $D$ is not square, its Galois group must be $S_3$, hence splitting field would be $\Q(\theta,{\sqrt D})$ . However I can't construct isomorphism from $\Q[x,y,z]/I$ to $\Q(\theta, {\sqrt D})$.

For other direction, I can't find any way to prove at all.

Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the idea is that if you factor $t^3 + at^2 + bt + c = (t - x)(t-y)(t-z)$, then $a,b,c$ are symmetric functions in the roots $x,y,z$ as given by the generators of $I$, e.g., $b = xy + xz + yz$.  Also, I would expect that the elimination ideal $I \cap \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is exactly $(f(x))$, the ideal generated by $f$.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my request quickly. Yes, if $I$ is maximal, then $Q[x,y,z]/I$ is a field containing $\bar(x)$, $\bar(y)$ and $\bar(z)$ and these generate $Q[x,y,z]/I$. So $Q[x,y,z]/I$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$. However, how would I know $I$ is maximal if $I$ is a prime. (similarly, iff $D$ is not asquare in $Q$). For later part, I am sure that Grobner basis of $I$ is $(x^{3} + ax^{2} + bx + c, x^{2} + xy + ax + y^{2} + ay + b, x + y + z + a)$ with monomial ordering $z>y>x$ hence $I\cap Q[x]$ is ideal generated by $f(x)$. But I can't proceed any more...could you help me? Thanks